# List<T>.Sort sorting nulls incorrectly

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a list of objects, some of which can be null. I want it sorted by some property, with `null`s at the end of list. However, `List<T>.Sort()` method seems to put `null`s in the beginning no matter what the comparer returns. This is a little program that I used to test this:

```
class Program
 {
  class Foo {
   public int Bar;
   public Foo(int bar)
   {
    Bar = bar;
   }
  }
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
   List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>{null, new Foo(1), new Foo(3), null, new Foo(100)};

   foreach (var foo in list)
   {
     Console.WriteLine("Foo: {0}", foo==null?"NULL":foo.Bar.ToString());
   }

   Console.WriteLine("Sorting:");
   list.Sort(new Comparer());
   foreach (var foo in list)
   {
    Console.WriteLine("Foo: {0}", foo == null ? "NULL" : foo.Bar.ToString());
   }
   Console.ReadKey();
  }
  class Comparer:IComparer<Foo>
  {
   #region Implementation of IComparer<in Foo>

   public int Compare(Foo x, Foo y)
   {
    int xbar = x == null ? int.MinValue : x.Bar;
    int ybar = y == null ? int.MinValue : y.Bar;
    return ybar - xbar;
   }

   #endregion
  }
 }
```

Try this yourself: sorted list is printed as

```
Foo: NULL
Foo: NULL
Foo: 100
Foo: 3
Foo: 1
```

`null`s Are first, even though they're compared as `int.Minvalue`. Is the method buggy or what?

Comment: [Never use subtraction to implement CompareTo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728793/java-integer-what-is-faster-comparison-or-subtraction/2728858#2728858)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let’s say `x` is `null` and `y` is 1.

```
int xbar = x == null ? int.MinValue : x.Bar;
int ybar = y == null ? int.MinValue : y.Bar;
return ybar - xbar;
```

So now we have `1 - int.MinValue`. This will be an overflow, so the end result will be **negative**, hence the `null` will be considered less than 1.

For that reason, the computation is fundamentally flawed.

```
public int Compare(Foo x, Foo y)
{
    int xbar = x == null ? int.MinValue : x.Bar;
    int ybar = y == null ? int.MinValue : y.Bar;
    return ybar.CompareTo(xbar);
}
```

(Thanks to the commenters for pointing out the flaw in my method.)

Comment: If Bar is comparable then I'd recommend using `x.Bar.CompareTo(y.Bar)`

Comment: So what if x == null and y == null?

Comment: @Garry: rather the other way round, since the ordering should be inverted.

Comment: @Konrad Ah yes, missed that bit. My main point was to lean on the type's implementation of IComparable where possible rather than reimplementing it.

Comment: You will get a runtime error with this as it expects to get zero when the object is being compared to each other. There needs to be a if (x==null && y==null) return 0; first

Comment: @Dave: unimportant for the sake of this sorting. But you’re right, and yours is a much simpler fix … (+1 on your answer).

Answer (score 13):

Your implementation is incorrect because you failed to **write the specification first, then write code that meets the specification.**

So, start over. Write a specification:

- FooCompare takes two references to Foo, x and y. Either may be null.
- IComparer.Compare(x,y) is documented as returning zero if x and y are equal, negative if y is greater than x, and positive if y is smaller than x.  We will follow this convention.
- if x and y are both null, they are equal.
- if one is null and the other one is not then the null one is the smaller.
- if neither are null then the comparison is based on the value of the Bar property.

And now you can write code that you are *guaranteed* matches the spec:

```
// FooCompare takes two references to Foo, x and y. Either may be null.
// +1 means x is larger, -1 means y is larger, 0 means they are the same.

int FooCompare(Foo x, Foo y)
{
    // if x and y are both null, they are equal.
    if (x == null && y == null) return 0;
    // if one is null and the other one is not then the non-null one is larger.
    if (x != null && y == null) return 1; 
    if (y != null && x == null) return -1; 
    // if neither are null then the comparison is 
    // based on the value of the Bar property.
    var xbar = x.Bar; // only calculate x.Bar once
    var ybar = y.Bar; // only calculate y.Bar once
    if (xbar > ybar) return 1;
    if (ybar > xbar) return -1;
    return 0;
}

// The original poster evidently wishes the list to be sorted from
// largest to smallest, where null is the smallest.
// Reverse the polarity of the neutron flow:
int Compare(Foo x, Foo y)
{
    return FooCompare(y, x);
}
```

Don't mess around with clever integer arithmetic tricks; as you've seen, clever equals buggy. **Correctness first.**

Comment: Funny thing is, that's exactly what I did. But it wasn't working correctly. Then I tried to change it to find out what's wrong, and made the version I put here, and it still didn't work. I was working with Mono in Unity3d; befuddled, I decided to try to reproduce this behavior in .NET. And it "reproduced" because I forgot about overflow.

Your code is in fact correct and works in .NET like it should. But it doesn't work in Unity3d's Mono, which is probably a bug (and I'll go to their site now and ask there).

Comment: Eric, a buddy of mine pointed out that you may have mixed up the return values when one reference is null and one is not. Based upon your specifications `else if (x == null && y != null) return -1;` should return `1` and `else if (x != null && y == null) return 1;` should return `-1` if null values should appear at the end of the sorted list.

Comment: @Brian: I'm not following you. How does my implementation not match the specification? The spec says "returns -1 if x is greater than y", and "if one is null and the other is not then the null one is the greater". Surely "if (x == null && y != null) return -1" implements those two lines of the specification. Why do you believe this to be incorrect?

Comment: @Eric: +1, very well said, though you did [mix your signs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.compare%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: @BlueRaja and @Brian, ah, thank you, yes, you are right. The problem here is that the *spec* is wrong. The reason that the spec is wrong is because I was matching the original poster's design. Notice how it returns ybar - xbar. If ybar is 10 and xbar is 3 then it returns 7, which indicates that x is *greater* than y according to the docs, but in fact 10 is greater than 3. This is because the original poster is attempting to sort the list into *reverse* order. Hence my confusion.

Comment: I've rewritten the code to follow the conventions of IComparer.

Answer (score 4):

Replace this line:

```
return ybar - xbar;
```

with this line:

```
return ybar.CompareTo(xbar);
```

Because your arithmetic is overflowing.

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation of `IComparer.Compare` is unnecessarily complex. Remember that all that matters about the return value is the sign - the magnitude is unimportant. To have `null`s compare less than all real `Foo`s, simply defer to `Int32`s implementation of `CompareTo`, after making your substitution:

```
return       (x == null ? int.MinValue : x.Bar)
  .CompareTo((y == null ? int.MinValue : y.Bar))
```

Answer (score 0):

int.MinValue is `-2147483648`.

Now, suppose you were comparing `3` and `-2147483648` via subtraction, specifically `3 - (-2147483648`?

Also you should consider using the null coalescing operator `??`

Comment: How would you use the null coalesce operator here? You can’t coalesce anything here, unless you define a null placeholder object for `Foo` – then you could use `(x ?? NullPlaceholder).Bar`.

Comment: Well, foo is essentially an integer with the option to be declared `null` so I'd replace `Foo` with `int?` and null coalesce them.  Sorry if that wasn't clear.