# Java Integer compareTo() - why use comparison vs. subtraction?

Tags: java, optimization, integer, comparison, integer-overflow

I've found that `java.lang.Integer` implementation of `compareTo` method looks as follows:

```
public int compareTo(Integer anotherInteger) {
    int thisVal = this.value;
    int anotherVal = anotherInteger.value;
    return (thisVal<anotherVal ? -1 : (thisVal==anotherVal ? 0 : 1));
}
```

The question is why use comparison instead of subtraction:

```
return thisVal - anotherVal;
```

Comment: When we're so quick to worry about micro-optimization, we often end up with buggy code.

Comment: As of JDK 7, one can use `Integer.compare(thisVal, anotherVal)` instead of writing out the ternary expression.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

This is due to integer overflow. When `thisVal` is very large and `anotherVal` is negative then subtracting the latter from the former yields a result that is bigger than `thisVal` which may overflow to the negative range.

Comment: Yeah the way they've done it here is probably more efficient than checking for overflow et al

Comment: Use Guava ComparisonChain. It is very handy!
https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.html

Comment: `thisVal` doesn’t need to be large. `thisVal` might be even zero and `anotherVal` be `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and you already have an overflow. And mind that, of course, it also could be the other way round, `thisValue` very small and `anotherVal` rather large, to have a distance that overflows the `int` value range.

Answer (score 70):

**The subtraction "trick" to compare two numerical value is broken!!!**

```
        int a = -2000000000;
        int b =  2000000000;
        System.out.println(a - b);
        // prints "294967296"
```

Here, `a < b`, yet `a - b` is positive.

DO NOT use this idiom. It doesn't work.

Moreover, *even if it does work*, it will *NOT* provide any significant improvement in performance, and may in fact cost readability.

#### See also

- [*Java Puzzlers*](http://www.javapuzzlers.com/) Puzzle 65: A Strange Saga of Suspicious Sort

  > This puzzle has several lessons. The most specific is: **Do not use a subtraction-based comparator unless you are sure that the difference between values will never be greater than** `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. More generally, beware of `int` overflow. Another lesson is that you should avoid "clever" code. Strive to write clear, correct code, and do not optimize it unless it proves necessary.

Comment: It's not really broken at all. If you know anything about the numbers you're comparing, you'll probably know that they're safe to compare. Even not knowing, just `((long)a - b)` ought to work. Though you're right; it's very rarely useful.

Comment: @naiad just doing `((long)a - b)` does not help, as you have to cast the result back to `int`, as that’s what the comparator has to return, ending up again with an overflow. You would have to do something like `Long.signum` on the result, which is easy to forget, as your comment shows. And it might not even be more efficient than `Integer.compare`, which the JVM might handle intrinsically…

Answer (score 9):

Simply speaking, the `int` type is not big enough to store the difference between two arbitrary `int` values. For example, the difference between 1.5 billion and -1.5 billion is 3.0 billion, but `int` cannot hold values greater than 2.1 billion.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it's to avoid overflow / underflow.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the overflow thing, you should note that the version with substraction *does not give the same results*.

- The first compareTo version returns one of three possible values: -1, 0, or 1.
- If you replace the last line with substraction, the result can be any integer value.

If you know there will be no overflow, you could use something like this:

```
public int compareTo(Integer anotherInteger) {
    return sign(this.value - anotherInteger.valuel);
}
```

Comment: You are correct that the results are not the same. But they are not required to be! `compareTo` is only required to return a negative value, zero or a positive value, depending on the sort order of `this` and the other object. See http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29