# How to sort an array or ArrayList<Point> ASC first by x and then by y?

Tags: java, c++, sorting, comparison

I just want to use Collections.sort or Arrays.sort to sort a list of points (class Point) by x first and then by y.

I have a class Ponto that implements Comparable like this:

```
public int compareTo(Ponto obj) {
        Ponto tmp = obj;
        if (this.x < tmp.x) {
            return -1;
        } else if (this.x > tmp.x) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

but now I want to sort by y too after x.

How can I do that by modifying the above code? Or is that a better and "clean" way to do this?
I also use to pass this code to C++, in which I've created a structure called Point with a equivalent comparable method.

Comment: What is the type of `this.x`, is it int, float, double...?

Comment: x and y are integers. I've only created a Ponto classe to implement the Comparable<> interface and to have x,y integers instead of doubles.I already saw the suggestions below. Thank you for your contribution too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `return 0` by the same comparison algo on `this.y` and `obj.y`.

By the way, reassigning to `tmp` is unnecessary here. The optimized picture can look like:

```
public int compareTo(Ponto other) {
    if (this.x == other.x) {
        return (this.y < other.y) ? -1 : ((this.y == other.y) ? 0 : 1);
    } else {
        return (this.x < other.x) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, you shouldn't use this subtraction technique unless you can guarantee that it will not overflow (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728793/java-integer-what-is-faster-comparison-or-subtraction/)

Answer (score 2):

BalusC provides the correct answer: basically you give priority to `x` over `y`. Here's a variant written using nested ternary operators that makes the priority clear.

```
public int compareTo(Ponto other) {
    return
      (this.x < other.x) ? -1 :
      (this.x > other.x) ? +1 :
      (this.y < other.y) ? -1 :
      (this.y > other.y) ? +1 :
      0;
}
```

Another way to do this, if you don't want to write a custom `Comparator<T>` for every priority scheme, is to do multiple sort using a *stable* algorithm.

If you want to order by `x` (primary), and then `y` (secondary), then:

- Sort on `y` first (!!!)
- Then sort on `x` using a stable sort

This is asymptotically still `O(N log N)` but of course you're doing multiple phases. It's convenient when you have many sorting criterias. Rather than writing the complex code, just do the multiple phase (and only optimize if/when proven necessary).

So if you have sorting keys `k1`, `k2`, `k3`, ..., `kM`, in that order of priority, you do:

- Sort on `kM`
- Stable sort on `kM-1`
- ...
- Stable sort on `k1`
- DONE!

Note that [`Collections.sort`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) is stable.

> This sort is guaranteed to be *stable*: equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort.

Comment: @BalusC: only if you're comfortable with nested ternary. I've been screamed at for using it before.

Comment: You get used to it after years. It's like delicious liquor for the old as compared to tasteless beer for the young.

Comment: And what if I use Ponto[] list and then sort it with Arrays.sort(list), is it as stable as Collections.sort?This is for a contest, but fortunatelly I know that my list will have no more than 50 elements.

Comment: @newba: you should learn how to read the documentation; that way you can answer these kinds of questions on your own quickly: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object[]%29 "This sort is guaranteed to be stable: equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort."