# ArrayList of my objects, indexOf problem

Tags: java, object, arraylist, indexof

I have problem with Java's ArrayList. I've created an Object, that contains two attributes, x and y. Now I've loaded some object in my ArrayList. Problem is that I don't know how to find index of some object with x atribute I'm searching. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming something like:

```
public class Point {
   public final int x;
   public final int y;
}
```

And a declaration of:

```
List<Point> points = ...;
```

You can use for-each to iterate through all the points and find the one you want:

```
for (Point p : points) {
   if (p.x == targetX) {
      process(p);
      break; // optional
   }
}
```

Note that this will not give you the *index*, but it will give you the `Point` itself, which sometimes is enough. If you really need the index, then you'd want to use indexed for loop, using `size()` and `get(int index)` (see BalusC's answer).

#### See also

- [Java Language Guide: the for-each loop](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)
- [`java.util.List` API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

---

The above solution searches in `O(N)` for each `targetX`. If you're doing this often, then you can improve this by declaring `class Point implements`[`Comparable<Point>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), using `x` as the primary sorting key for [`Collections.sort`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29).

Then you can [`Collections.binarySearch`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator%29). With a setup time of `O(N log N)`, each query can now be answered in `O(log N)`.

Another option is to use a [`SortedSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) such as a [`TreeSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), especially if what you have is a [`Set<Point>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), not a [`List<Point>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

#### See also

- [How to sort an array or `ArrayList<Point>` ASC first by `x` and then by `y`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741846/how-to-sort-an-array-or-arraylistpoint-asc-first-by-x-and-then-by-y/)
- [Java: What is the difference between implementing Comparable and Comparator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440134/java-what-is-the-difference-between-implementing-comparable-and-comparator)

Comment: He's interested in the index.

Comment: @BalusC: yes, I just saw the `[indexOf]` tag; referring to your answer instead of duping.

Answer (score 7):

Is this what you looking for?

```
public class Point {

private final int x;
private final int y;

public Point(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return (o instanceof Point && getX() == ((Point) o).getX() && getY() == ((Point) o)
            .getY());

}
```

}

```
public class TestIndexOf {

public static void main(String[] args){
    Point p1 = new Point(10,30);
    Point p2 = new Point(20,40);
    Point p3 = new Point(50,40);
    Point p4 = new Point(60,40);
    List<Point> list = new ArrayList<Point>();
    list.add(p1);
    list.add(p2);
    list.add(p3);
    list.add(p4);
    System.out.println(list.indexOf(p3));
}
```

}

If you just want to search on the x property, change the equals method to compare only the x values like:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return (o instanceof Point && getX() == ((Point) o).getX());

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just iterate over the list and test every element.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (list.get(i).getX() == someValue) { // Or use equals() if it actually returns an Object.
        // Found at index i. Break or return if necessary.
    }
}
```

Verbose, yes, but possibly until JDK7 with [Closures](http://javac.info), there is no other standard way.

Answer (score 0):

I usually just use a map if i want to be able to fetch an object out of a collection based on one specific attribute value. I find that cleaner than having to iterate over lists.

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

map.put(o1.getX(), o1);
map.put(o2.getX(), o2);
```

now, if i want the object that has an x-value of "foo", all it takes is

```
Object desiredObject = map.get("foo");
```

if order is important, consider a LinkedHashMap.