# Create a SortedMap in Java with a custom Comparator

Tags: java, string, sorting, comparator, treemap

I want to create a `TreeMap` in Java with a custom sort order. The sorted keys which are string need to be sorted according to the second character. The values are also string.

Sample map:

```
Za,FOO
Ab,Bar
```

Comment: A `TreeMap` doesn't use `hashCode()`. What do you mean by "a sorted hash"? Do you mean to say `SortedMap<K,V>`?

Comment: @kunjaan - In Java terminology, an associative array is referred to as a "map" not a "hash" ... especially when you are talking about a Map type that does not use hashing!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use a custom comparator like this:

```
    Comparator<String> secondCharComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            return s1.substring(1, 2).compareTo(s2.substring(1, 2));
        }           
    };
```

Sample:

```
    SortedMap<String,String> map =
        new TreeMap<String,String>(secondCharComparator);
    map.put("Za", "FOO");
    map.put("Ab", "BAR");
    map.put("00", "ZERO");
    System.out.println(map); // prints "{00=ZERO, Za=FOO, Ab=BAR}"
```

Note that this simply assumes that the `String` has a character at index 1. It throws `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` if it doesn't.

---

Alternatively, you can also use this comparison:

```
return s1.charAt(1) - s2.charAt(1);
```

This subtraction "trick" is broken in general, but it works fine here because the subtraction of two `char` will not overflow an `int`.

The `substring` and`compareTo` solution above is more readable, though.

#### See also:

- [Java Integer: what is faster comparison or subtraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728793/java-integer-what-is-faster-comparison-or-subtraction)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't mean Hash as in hash function or the sort...

You could easily accomplish this by creating a "wrapper" class for String and overriding the compareTo method