# Remove duplicate strings from an arraylist<Object>

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist, duplicates

My program is opening a file and then saves its words and their byte distance from the file beginning . Though the file has too many duplicate words that i don't want . Also i want my list to be in alphabetical order . The problem is that when i fix the order the duplicate are messed and vice versa . Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Set;

class MyMain {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            ArrayList<DictPage> listOfWords = new ArrayList<DictPage>(); 
            LinkedList<Page> Eurethrio = new LinkedList<Page>(); 
            File file = new File("C:\\Kennedy.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
            //This will reference one line at a time...
            String line = null;
            int line_count=0;
            int byte_count; 
            int total_byte_count=0; 
            int fromIndex;

            int kat = 0;
            while( (line = br.readLine())!= null ){
                line_count++;
                fromIndex=0;
                String [] tokens = line.split(",\\s+|\\s*\\\"\\s*|\\s+|\\.\\s*|\\s*\\:\\s*");
                String line_rest=line;
                for (int i=1; i <= tokens.length; i++) {
                    byte_count = line_rest.indexOf(tokens[i-1]);
                    //if ( tokens[i-1].length() != 0)
                    //System.out.println("\n(line:" + line_count + ", word:" + i + ", start_byte:" + (total_byte_count + fromIndex) + "' word_length:" + tokens[i-1].length() + ") = " + tokens[i-1]);
                    fromIndex = fromIndex + byte_count + 1 + tokens[i-1].length();
                    if (fromIndex < line.length())
                        line_rest = line.substring(fromIndex);
                    if(!listOfWords.contains(tokens[i-1])){//Na mhn apothikevetai h idia leksh
                        //listOfWords.add(tokens[i-1]);
                        listOfWords.add(new DictPage(tokens[i-1],kat));
                        kat++;
                    }

                    Eurethrio.add(new Page("Kennedy",fromIndex));
                    }
                    total_byte_count += fromIndex;
                    Eurethrio.add(new Page("Kennedy", total_byte_count));
            }

            Set<DictPage> hs = new HashSet<DictPage>();
            hs.addAll(listOfWords);
            listOfWords.clear();
            listOfWords.addAll(hs);

            if (listOfWords.size() > 0) {
                Collections.sort(listOfWords, new Comparator<DictPage>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(final DictPage object1, final DictPage object2) {
                        return object1.getWord().compareTo(object2.getWord());
                    }
                   } );
               }
            //Ektypwsh leksewn...
            for (int i = 0; i<listOfWords.size();i++){
                System.out.println(""+listOfWords.get(i).getWord()+" "+listOfWords.get(i).getPage());
            }
            for (int i = 0;i<Eurethrio.size();i++){
                System.out.println(""+Eurethrio.get(i).getFile()+" "+Eurethrio.get(i).getBytes());
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove repeated elements from ArrayList?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist)

Comment: Either first sort the list and then construct the set (you could use a `LinkedHashSet` to preserve order) or use a `TreeSet` as already has been suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the TreeSet instead of ArrayList, and you'll get automatically order and no repeatings.

Comment: i get this error when i use tree set :
DictPage cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Comment: Sure. You should create your own Comporator for DictPage. Look here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748829/create-a-sortedmap-in-java-with-a-custom-comparator

Answer (score 0):

use this.

```
public void stripDuplicatesFromFile(String filename) {
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
                Set<String> lines = new HashSet<String>(); 
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    lines.add(line);
                }
                reader.close();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
                for (String unique : lines) {
                    writer.write(unique);
                    writer.newLine();
                }
                writer.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

it takes filepath as an input, find duplicate lines and remove them. But if you have large file do not use this. I'm using this method on a very small size of a .txt file (kind of log file and order is not imported).

Comment: There are several issues here: 1) OP doesn't seem to want to write back to a file 2) order would not be preserved nor does your code sort 3) It doesn't make use of `DictPage` nor does the code operate on individual words 4) (more a personal viewpoint) just posting code without any explanation of what's different and why is not going to help that much.

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, why are you using `ArrayList` to store your list of words.

```
ArrayList<DictPage> listOfWords = new ArrayList<DictPage>();
```

You should use `Set` (like `HashSet`, `TreeSet` or some implementation of `Set`) to store your words if you don't want duplicates.

```
 Set<DictPage> listOfWords = new Hashset<DictPage>(); //no duplicates but not sorted
```

Or

```
Set<DictPage> listOfWords = new Treeset<DictPage>(); //no duplicates and sorted as well
```

This would make sure that your list of words does not contain any duplicates.

And if you want them sorted straight away, you can use `TreeSet` which will make it more easier for you.