# Sorting a Map by an attribute of object

Tags: java, sorting, object, hashmap

Disclaimer :  I have already once posted such a question and it was marked duplicate. Please try and help me. I have gone through all previous methods on stackoverflow and none was of any help. All the methods mentioned to sort Map(Key,Values) didn't work in my case as I have one step further i.e. retrieving the attribute of the value. This time, I tried to go with full detail.

I've a Map (String,Object) in Java and I want to sort it using one of the attributes of the Object.

e.g. Suppose I have a class

```
class Entry
{
    int id;
    String name;
    String address;
    //Rest of the code
}
```

Now, I created a map

```
 Map<String,Entry>
```

I want to sort the map by the attribute id of the class Entry (Entry.id)

Please help !

For example, I have three objects of Entry class

```
entry1 :
        id=1
        name="abc"
        address="india"
entry2 :
        id=2
        name="xyz"
        address="india"
entry3 :
        id=3
        name="pqr"
        address="india"
```

Now, I have the Map initially as follows :

```
Key :   Value
first:  entry2
second: entry3
third : entry1
```

After sorting, it should be like

```
Key :   Value
third : entry1
first:  entry2
second: entry3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a SortedMap in Java with a custom Comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748829/create-a-sortedmap-in-java-with-a-custom-comparator)

Comment: It is impossible to sort `Map` by values or attributes of values in Java out of the box. Depending on what you really need to do with that sorted `Map` you might need to have a separate data structure for sorted objects

Comment: Why do you want the map (entries) sorted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily accomplish the task with the stream API:

```
Map<String, Entry> resultSet = myMap.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(e -> e.getValue().getId()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                        Map.Entry::getValue,
                        (left, right) -> left,
                        LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: “easy” is obviously subjective. This doesn’t look easy to me.

Comment: @Bohemian what difficulty are you having to to understand the code?

Comment: IMHO it’s what I call a “train wreck”. You can **not** understand what your code is doing at a glance. That fact makes it rank lower on the “goodness” scale. Compare your code with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50453540/256196) (which I *think* works).

Comment: @Bohemian "IMHO" is obviously subjective as well.

Comment: @Bohemian Further, when you say "You can not understand what your code is doing at a glance." I don't see anything difficult to understand here, this is as simple as it gets when all you want to do is sort the map.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is typically a symptom of bad data-structure usage.

If you wanted the map to be sorted by an attribute of key objects, you would just write a custom comparator, but since you want to sort by values, it's a bit more complicated.

Try understanding answers to this question: [Sort a Map<Key, Value> by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values). And then try using a custom comparator in combination.

Answer (score -3):

You can’t sort a map.

You can have a map that keeps its entries sorted, or you can sort a `List<Map.Entry>`.

Try this:

```
Map<String, Entry> map; // your map
Map<String, Entry> sorted = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparing(s -> map.get(s).getId());
sorted.putAll(map);
```

Comment: more efficient to use `Comparator.comparingInt` as opposed to `Comparator.comparing`

Comment: @Aominè more efficient? It’s more code and I doubt you could measure the difference in timing.

Comment: Seriously... more code by _only_ 3 letters. Yes you could measure the difference and why go for a suboptimal solution when you can go to the most optimal solution by only adding 3 letters. It’s a no brainer really, I’d jump at having the most optimal code all the time.

Comment: @Aominè let’s get something straight: in virtually all applications (all except super low latency requirements like ticker processing, where they don’t even run a garbage collector), you could not measure the difference in performance - it would be single digit nanoseconds for what is more or less a one-time operation. There are other factors too: by coding `comparingInt()`, you’re locking in `int` as the type for `id`. If that changed to a String or guid, you’d have to come back here and change this code too. Using `comparing()` is more flexible, it works with all types - that’s good practice

Comment: I have the feeling the more I reply to your comments we’ll be here for eternity so let’s call it a day.