# How do I use a Lambda expression to sort INTEGERS inside a object?

Tags: c#, collections, lambda

I have a collection of objects and I know that I can sort by NAME (string type) by saying

```
collEquipment.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.ItemName, y.ItemName));
```

that WORKS.

But I want to sort by a ID (integer type) and there is no such thing as Int32.Compare

So how do I do this?  This doesn't work

```
collEquipment.Sort((x, y) => (x.ID < y.ID));  //error
```

I know the answer is going to be really simple. Lambda expressions confuse me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this

```
collEquipment.Sort((x, y) => y.ID - x.ID);
```

Comment: possibly has some wrap-around issues with very large numbers

Comment: great works thanks!  its just IDs for items in a DB.. so won't be too large

Comment: @Marc Gravell - I guess this would be the same case for any method right?

Comment: You shouldn't use `-` to implement CompareTo - it does not work (overflow problems etc.)

Comment: Still don't get how "y.ID - x.ID" = "Sort these integers"

Have to study more.

Comment: @punkouter:  He is using subtraction to implement CompareTo, which is flawed.  See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728793/java-integer-what-is-faster-comparison-or-subtraction).

Comment: @punkouter: The sort func needs to return a 0, >0, or a <0 result.  Subtracting the compare values will do that (more or less), but it would be better to use the Int32.CompareTo() method.  So replace y.ID - x.ID with y.ID.CompareTo(x.ID), as JWL_ pointed out below.

Answer (score 16):

```
collEquipment.Sort((x, y) => y.ID.CompareTo(x.ID));
```

Comment: The short explanation of *why* this works is that Sort does not take a less-than operator - it takes a "comparator" operator which returns <0 if x<y, >0 if x>y, or 0 if x==y. So it always expects an integer result, not a boolean. The CompareTo() method on int returns <0, 0, or >0 in this pattern, so you can use it to solve your problem succinctly, although using if-else would work as well (if (x.ID<y.ID) return -1; else if (x.ID>y.ID) return 1; else return 0;).

Answer (score 8):

Here you go, sort a list against any property that implements `IComparable[<T>]` (which `int` does):

```
public static class ListExtensions {
    public static void Sort<TSource, TValue>(
        this List<TSource> list,
        Func<TSource, TValue> selector) {
        list.Sort((x,y) => Comparer<TValue>.Default
            .Compare(selector(x),selector(y)));
    }
}
```

Now:

```
collEquipment.Sort(x => x.ItemName);
```

or

```
collEquipment.Sort(x => x.ID);
```