# Sort a list of objects by the value of a property

Tags: c#

I have a list of cities.

```
 List<City> cities;
```

I'd like to sort the list by population.  The code I'm imagining is something like:

```
 cities.Sort(x => x.population);
```

but this doesn't work.  How should I be sorting this list?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766686/how-do-i-use-a-lambda-expression-to-sort-integers-inside-a-object

Comment: Joe, you have to have two arguments. One is the item and the other is the comparer. Check the example in the post I linked

Comment: Let me see if I've got this right.  The `Sort` function takes only one argument, which is a lambda/delegate that takes *two* arguments and should work like a <=> operator?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use OrderBy of Linq function. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx

```
cities.OrderBy(x => x.population);
```

Comment: It's important to note that unline Sort, OrderBy does not modify the input.

Comment: Or if you want to simply output the list in reverse order, you can use `cities.Reverse()`

Comment: alternatively: OrderByDescending

Answer (score 19):

Use this ,this will work.

```
List<cities> newList = cities.OrderBy(o=>o.population).ToList();
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do this without LINQ. See the IComparable interface documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
cities.Sort((x,y) => x.Population - y.Population)
```

Or you can put this Comparison function within the City class,

```
public class City : IComparable<City> 
{
    public int Population {get;set;}

    public int CompareTo(City other)
    {
        return Population - other.Population;
    }
 ...
}
```

Then you can just do,

```
cities.Sort()
```

And it will return you the list sorted by population.

Answer (score 2):

As another option, if you aren't fortunate enough to be able to use Linq, you can use the IComparer or IComparable interface.

Here is a good KB article on the two interfaces:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320727