# Calling arrays from other methods in a different class

Tags: java, arrays

I need help dealing with an array in my java program. in my first class, "test", I set 4 variables and then send them to my other class (test2).

`arr[i] = new test2(id, fname, lname, case);`

at that point, variables are set and then I want to return those variables. So in the test2 class, I have a method that strictly returns one of those variables

```
public int getId(){
return id;
}
```

I understand this is a little stupid, but professor gets what professor wants I guess. What I want to do now is in my main method in "test" I want to retrieve that variable and sort the array based on that int. Unfortunately, I have to create my own sort function, but I think this would work for what I want to do.

```
for(j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
   int indexMin =j;

   for(i = j; i < arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i] < arr[indexMin]){
     indexMin = i;
    }
   }
   int tmp = arr[j];
   arr[j] = arr[indexMin];
   arr[indexMin] = tmp;
  }
```

I appreciate any help anyone could provide. 
Thank you

Comment: Sorry if that was not clear. I do not know how to call the returned values from my method in class test2. A great helpful hint for me would be if someone told me how to print to screen all the ID's in the array..

Answer (score 2):

So a few comments:

-Your loop looks like this:

```
for(i = j; i < arr.length; i++)
```

You should be declaring

```
for(int i = j; i< arr.length; i++);
```

Either you hadn't declared i yet, which would give you a compilation error, or you declared i earlier which is not ideal...you avoid bugs better by declaring variables as locally as possible.

-In this line you directly compare objects:

```
if(arr[i] < arr[indexMin]){
```

but if I understand your intent correctly, you want to be comparing the IDs, so this should look like

```
if(arr[i].getId() < arr[indexMin].getId()){
```

-It looks like arr is an array of test2 objects, but you assign one to an int for your swapping code:

```
int tmp = arr[j];
```

This should be

```
test2 tmp = arr[j];
```

As far as your algorithm, why don't you get your code up and running and then try testing with a few results. What about 4 objects with IDs 1, 2, 3 and 4? How about 4, 3, 2, and 1? You'll learn more by playing around with it manually than if I tell you an algorithm here. Don't be afraid to add some statements that help you see exactly what's going on when. For example, maybe you might change the last 4 lines to look like:

```
System.out.println("About to swap id " + arr[j].getId() + " from index " + j + " with minimum " + arr[indexMin].getId() + " at index " + indexMin);
test2 tmp = arr[j];
arr[j] = arr[indexMin];
arr[indexMin] = tmp;
```

This will help you sooner get to the bottom of what's happening when in your program, and don't be afraid to add more similar stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Make [`Test2 implements Comparable<Test2>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and use [`java.util.Arrays.sort(Object[])`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) instead.

The `compareTo(Test2)` would look something like this:

```
@Override int public compareTo(Test2 other) {
   return
     (this.id < other.id) ? -1 :
     (this.id > other.id) ? +1 :
     0;
}
```

Even better is if you can switch to `List<Test2>` (*Effective Java 2nd Edition: Item 25: Prefer lists to arrays*).

#### See also

- [Java Integer: what is faster comparison or subtraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728793/java-integer-what-is-faster-comparison-or-subtraction/)

  - **DO NOT** be tempted to be "clever" and use `this.id - other.id`. This comparison-by-subtraction trick is broken.
- [Java Naming convention](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc8.html)

  - Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.

---

If you have to implement your own sort, then in place of `arr[i] < arr[indexMin]`, you want `arr[i].getId() < arr[indexMin].getId()`. This assumes that it was declared `Test2[] arr;`

If for some reason it was declared as `Object[] arr` instead, then you'd just need to cast them to `Test2` before you can invoke `getId()`.

```
((Test2) arr[i]).getId() < ((Test2) arr[indexMin]).getId()
```

You'd also want to declare `Test2 tmp` instead of `int tmp` for the swap.

---

As for printing, you can use a for-each loop:

```
for (Test2 t : arr) {
   System.out.println(t);
}
```

This assumes that `Test2` has `@Override`[`public String toString()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) that is sensible for printing, but otherwise you can access the member methods individually.

#### See also

- [Java language guide/for-each loop](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

Comment: The OP has to implement the sort himself.

Comment: @Peter: Oh, it's a course professor? I thought maybe it's a research professor.