# Why is comparing ints safe in Java?

Tags: java, integer-overflow

Why, given:

```
int a = ..., b = ... ;
```

is this unsafe:

```
a - b
```

but this is safe:

```
a > b
```

By *safe* I mean guaranteed not to be affected by overflows (I'm writing a `Comparator` of ints).

Comment: If `a` is positive and `b` is negative and their difference is bigger than MAX_INTEGER, the overflow.

Comment: yes, please focus on the second part (`a>b`)

Comment: There's no possibility to overflow since you aren't adding or subtracting anywhere or multiplying/dividing, just comparing.

Comment: how is comparison of ints implemented then?

Comment: catch the overflow and `return a > 0`

Comment: *I'm writing a Comparator of ints* do not reinvent the wheel, use `Integer#compare(int a, int b)`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza please focus on the question :)

Comment: @Kiel Perhaps the underlying native code for comparison doesn't restrict the type to 4 bytes. You are [correct](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Microprocessor_Design/ALU_Flags) in saying `>` uses subtraction.

Comment: From [JSL 15.20.1. Numerical Comparison Operators <, <=, >, and >=](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.1): *Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands ... If the promoted type of the operands is int or long, then signed integer comparison is performed.* what don't you exactly understand? And by my last comment, I focused on the question: **do not reinvent the wheel**!

Comment: how is it performed so that it doesn't overflow. Please reread the question - it's "Why is comparing ints safe in Java?", not "How to write a comparator".

Comment: Why do you assume that a subtraction would be performed during a `>` operator?  The answer to your question is that "The spec says so."

Comment: Because atm I have no idea how to do this other way, plus i've seen this approach in asm code many times

Comment: This is mostly done by the JVM implementation. So, to get an *exact* answer you could review how HotSpot implements this, but you can't be sure since JRockit and IBM JVM can implement it in another way (just to mention some of them).

Comment: [This is an old JVM spec document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/Overview.doc.html) but it might be useful to you. See section `3.11.3 Arithmetic Instructions`

Comment: @Kiel: I'm curious.  Can you think of a way to implement it using a subtraction?  If so, what is it?

Comment: (afaik) intel cpu does comparison with `SUB`s, using both signed and usigned math

Comment: @Kiel Intel has lots of different CPU's.  Maybe the old 4004 used SUB for comparison ... but every CPU I've seen since after about 1970 has comparison instructions.  Plus, any compiler that does implement > as a subtract instruction would be smart enough to generate code that doesn't fault on overflow, so any intermediate overflows would be dealt with internally and hidden from the programmer.

Comment: I think the difference is that when using `<` the comparison is done by JVM who can check the state of overflow flag after `CMP`, while when you do `-` you can not determine if there was an overlfow

Comment: @ajb *to generate code that doesn't fault on overflow* - yeaah, this is what I'd expected to see in an answer - the code ;]

Answer (score 2):

The comparison `a > b` is itself safe, because neither `a` nor `b` are changed.  The operation `a - b` can be unsafe because overflow is possible.

However, a previous overflow may affect the correctness of such a comparison `a > b` done later.  Subtracting a really large negative number will result in overflow, in that the result can be less than the original number (in math, subtracting a negative number should increase the original number), meaning `a > b` may be an unexpected result.

If `a - b` is used in a `Comparator`, at first it looks like it satisfies the contract of `Comparator`: return a number less than zero, equal to zero, or greater than zero if the value is less than, equal to, or greater than another value.  But that's only true if overflow does not occur.

If `a = 1000` and `b = Integer.MIN_VALUE + 100` (a very large negative number, `-2147483548`), then `a - b` will overflow.  The true mathematical result would be `500 - Integer.MIN_VALUE`, a value larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (2147484548).  So the positive return value would indicate that `a > b`, which is obviously true.

But with overflow, the value winds up being less than zero (`-2147482748`), erroneously indicating that `a < b`.

Comment: @Kiel refer to the ASM code that will execute that comparison

Comment: The `<` operation also uses subtraction in assembly code, so the question, I think, is why does it not exhibit overflow behavior?

Comment: @LouisWasserman [ALUs](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Microprocessor_Design/ALU_Flags) typically do comparisons by calculating the difference of the two operands.

Comment: Then it's their responsibility to deal with sign problems, or the JIT's to generate assembly code that works around that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends... See [System.nanoTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29), which recommends `t1 - t0 < 0, not t1 < t0` for time comparison...

Comment: I think this is not because `<` can overflow but because of the nature of the value of `System.nanoTime()`, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18414157/594406