# How can the "<" or ">" operators overflow?

Tags: java, jvm, operators, overflow, nanotime

I am intrigued with the following statement found in the documentation of the System.nanoTime() method in Java:

```
long t0 = System.nanoTime();
```

...

```
long t1 = System.nanoTime();
```

***One should use `t1 - t0 < 0`, not `t1 < t0`, because of the possibility of numerical overflow***.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()

Why is it that `t1 < t0` might "overflow"? This is in the Javadocs, but I guess it applies to any language.

Comment: answer is here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414059/why-should-i-use-t1-t0-0-not-t1-t0-when-using-system-nanotime-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that `<` might overflow, it's that `t2` might overflow.

Examples in hexadecimal, because overflow is obvious in hexadecimal.

Say you call `System.nanoTime()` and the result is `0x7FFFFFFF00000000`. This is very close to the maximum value of a `long`. This is `t1`.

A few seconds later you call it again, and get `0x8000000011111111`. This is very close to the minimum value of a `long` - which means it's much smaller than the first value you got! This is `t2`.

If you checked `t2 < t1`, you'd get `false`, because `t2` is indeed less than `t1`.

If you calculate the difference `t2 - t1`, this also overflows, but it happens that this always cancels out the first overflow (if there was one). The result is `0x0000000111111111` which is the correct time difference. This is greater than 0, so `t2 - t1 > 0` returns `true`.

Comment: @DavidWallace your calculations are wrong then; it will be an issue in or before 2306. Remember it's 2^64 *nano*seconds.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what immibis  said, this source explain the difference between a < b and a-b < 0 with big long:

```
    long t1 = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    long t2 = Long.MIN_VALUE;
    //should have the same result with small longs, but is different when rotating from max value to min value of Long
    System.out.println(t1 - t2 < 0); //true
    System.out.println(t1 < t2); //false

    //should have the same result
    System.out.println(t1 - t2 > 0); // false
    System.out.println(t1 > t2); //true

    System.out.println(t2 - t1); // 1 => 1 nanosecond of difference
```

Since time in nanosceond can exceed the "long" size, when the time arrive to the max value, it begins again to the min value. So there is 1 nanesecond of difference between MAX_VALUE end MIN_VALUE