# Is there the matter with the compareTo return value?

Tags: java

While the contract for compareTo method specifies only the sign of return value, why almost the all method implementations return only  -1, 0, 1?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question more?

Comment: What else you suggest ?  a,b,c ??

Comment: Read the documentation. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Comment: please make your question clear !!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. ow us what you have tried, the relevant code and the **specific** issues you are having. We're not here to write it for you. Read up on [how to write a Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (](http://sscce.org/).  Then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25158221/edit) your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... why do almost the all method implementations return only -1, 0, 1?

I can't speak for other programmers, but I typically do this because it is simpler and more convenient to do that in most case.  And most important, it is **correct**.

I imagine that you are thinking along the lines of doing this:

```
  public int compareTo (MyClass other) {
      return this.intField - other.intField;
  }
```

Beware.  This code is subtly wrong.  See this Q&A: [Java Integer compareTo() - why use comparison vs. subtraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728793/java-integer-compareto-why-use-comparison-vs-subtraction)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I think you are very smart, because the others don't understand my clear question ;) They gave me a lot of minuses

Answer (score 0):

If you have the read the contract, you have read why.

I'll link it anyway: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)

Answer (score 0):

When you compare two values, say `a` and `b`. There are only 3 possibility.

`a` equals to `b`
`a` less than `b`
`a` greater than `b`

So then you use `compateTo()` you need to check above cases only. Then `0` means there are equals. `-1` mean `a` less than `b` and `1` means `a` greater than `b`

If `a` and `b` are objects then reference value consider.

Comment: @DividebyZero same way. Then reference value come in to play for Objects. are you downvote this?

Comment: no, i am not the downvoter, i love my reputation and not interested in loosing one by downvoting any answer(questions are exception though :p)...

Comment: @DividebyZero so? what is your point?