# TreeSet<Object> allowing multiple objects of same type

Tags: java, data-structures, treeset

I have a `TreeSet<Floor>` object which stores floors to be visited by an elevator. `Floor` is an abstract class which is extended by concrete floor class e.x FloorOne, FloorTwo etc. As per the logic my `TreeSet<Floor>` should store only one instance of each `Floor` subtype but instead I am able to insert multiple instances of each subtypes. `Floor` class implements `Comparable` so I can sort floors in `TreeSet<Floor>` as per their number. Below is the code for class `Floor`

```
public abstract class Floor implements Comparable<Floor>{

    protected int floorNo;
    public abstract void floorVisited();
    public int getFloorNo() {
        return floorNo;
    }   
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Floor floor) {
        return this.getFloorNo() > floorButton.getFloorNo() ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```

Code for one of the subtype:

```
public class FloorOne extends Floor{

    public FloorOne(){
        floorNo = 1;
    } 
    @Override
    public void floorVisited() {
        System.out.println("Floor No. " + floorNo + " was visited");
    }
}
```

adding floors to `TreeSet<Floor>` by calling addFloor() method of ElevatorController.

```
controller.addFloor(new FloorFour());
controller.addFloor(new FloorFour());
controller.addFloor(new FloorTwo());
```

addFloor() method in ElevatorController.

```
private TreeSet<Floor> travelUpwards;
private TreeSet<Floor> travelDownwards;

public void addFloor(Floor floor) {

    if (floor.getFloorNo() > currentFloor.getFloorNo()) {
        travelUpwards.add(floor);
    } else if (floor.getFloorNo() < currentFloor.getFloorNo()) {
        travelDownwards.add(floor);
    }
}
```

Output I'm getting is:

```
Floor No. 2 was visited
Floor No. 4 was visited
Floor No. 4 was visited
```

As per my understanding a new instance of object `FloorFour` is created when I call `addFloor(new FloorFour())` and that is why `TreeSet<Floor>` do not consider them as duplicate. But is there a way I can stop insertion of same floor more than once.

Comment: Your compareTo method is wrong. You should return the difference between the floors

Comment: Using a Set to store a data structure so obviously ordered as floors of a building doesn't seem like a good idea to me...

Comment: Your comparator does not correctly handle the case where floor numbers are equal

Comment: @AlexisDufrenoy @assylias - assylias, I wanted your opinion on this too. I considered `TreeSet` and `PriorityQueue`, because I need some natural ordering for floors in `UpwaredTravel' and `DownwardTravel` lists. The reason I chose `TreeSet` is because it does not allow duplicate entries which would otherwise be a great overhead as every time someone request a floor, we will have to check the respective list if it already has a request for that floor. In case of `PriorityQueue` this overhead was the reason for picking `TreeSet` over `PriorityQueue`. what you guys think could be a better pick.

Comment: @MeenaChaudhary Why not a List? Your lift is like an index on a sorted list of floors...

Comment: @AlexisDufrenoy for two reasons. First, `Lists` do not allow natural ordering so we have to call `Collections.sort(list)` every time a floor is added. And secondly, `Lists` allow duplicate elements hence will have to check list to make sure each floor is added only once. which is a overhead.

Comment: @MeenaChaudhary: You're wrong about the ordering. The Java API defines a List as "an ordered collection (also known as a sequence). The user of this interface has precise control over where in the list each element is inserted. The user can access elements by their integer index (position in the list), and search for elements in the list". Which means if you add a floor on top of the others (hence, at the end of the list), you have the guarantee it's where you will find it. The elements keep the order you define. You're right about the duplicates, though.

Answer (score 2):

Having a correct implementation of the compareTo() method would probably solve your problem.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Floor floor) {
    return this.getFloorNo() - floor.getFloorNo();
}
```

Comment: Although unlikely in this example, the subtraction could overflow. `return Integer.compare(this.getFloorNo(), floor.getFloorNo());` does not overflow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728793/java-integer-compareto-why-use-comparison-vs-subtraction for details.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Floor floor) {
    return this.getFloorNo() > floorButton.getFloorNo() ? 1 : -1;
}
```

This can never return zero, so it will never indicate that two floors are equal.
You should ensure you return zero when they are equal, rather than `-1`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `compareTo` method is wrong - it never allows floors to be "equal", and thus breaks the general contract of Java's `compareTo` method.

Since the floor number is an `int`, instead of reinventing the wheel, you should just use [`java.lang.Integer.compare(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int)):

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Floor floor) {
    return Integer.compare(this.getFloorNo(), floor.getFloorNo());
}
```