# How to sort based on/compare multiple values in Kotlin?

Tags: comparable, kotlin

Say I have a `class Foo(val a: String, val b: Int, val c: Date)` and I want to sort a list of `Foo`s based on all three properties. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Kotlin's stdlib offers a number of useful helper methods for this.

First, you can define a comparator using the [`compareBy()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/compare-by.html) method and pass it to the [`sortedWith()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/sorted-with.html) extension method to receive a sorted copy of the list:

```
val list: List<Foo> = ...
val sortedList = list.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.a }, { it.b }, { it.c }))
```

Second, you can let `Foo` implement `Comparable<Foo>` using the [`compareValuesBy()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/compare-values-by.html) helper method:

```
class Foo(val a: String, val b: Int, val c: Date) : Comparable<Foo> {
    override fun compareTo(other: Foo)
            = compareValuesBy(this, other, { it.a }, { it.b }, { it.c })
}
```

Then you can call the [`sorted()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/sorted.html) extension method without parameters to receive a sorted copy of the list:

```
val sortedList = list.sorted()
```

#### Sorting direction

If you need to sort ascending on some values and descending on other values, the stdlib also offers functions for that:

```
list.sortedWith(compareBy<Foo> { it.a }.thenByDescending { it.b }.thenBy { it.c })
```

#### Performance considerations

The `vararg` version of `compareValuesBy` is not inlined in the bytecode meaning anonymous classes will be generated for the lambdas. However, if the lambdas themselves don't capture state, singleton instances will be used instead of instantiating the lambdas everytime.

As noted by [Paul Woitaschek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3761545/paul-woitaschek) in the comments, comparing with multiple selectors will instantiate an array for the vararg call everytime. You can't optimize this by extracting the array as it will be copied on every call. What you can do, on the other hand, is extract the logic into a static comparator instance and reuse it:

```
class Foo(val a: String, val b: Int, val c: Date) : Comparable<Foo> {

    override fun compareTo(other: Foo) = comparator.compare(this, other)

    companion object {
        // using the method reference syntax as an alternative to lambdas
        val comparator = compareBy(Foo::a, Foo::b, Foo::c)
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that if you are using multiple lambdas functions (there is an overload with exactly one which inlines), they are **not inlined**. Which means each call to comapreTo creates a n new objects. To prevent that you could move the selectors to the companion object so the selectors are only allocated once. I created a snipped here: https://gist.github.com/PaulWoitaschek/7f3c4d5310a66ed4984785ee2d6f70ed

Comment: @PaulWoitaschek if the lambdas don't capture stat, they are compiled to singletons.

Comment: @KirillRakhman It creates singletons for the functions but still allocates arrays: `ANEWARRAY kotlin/jvm/functions/Function1`

Comment: @PaulWoitaschek I've looked at the bytecode and it seems your version allocates an array anyway, because the spread operator will use `Arrays.copyOf`.

Comment: Starting with Kotlin 1.1.3 `compareBy` with multiple lambdas won't allocate new array on every `compareTo` call.

Comment: @Ilya could you point me to the relevant changelog or other info for this kind of optimization?

Comment: @KirillRakhman https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/commit/6a15981b3ac5215af5c68eceaf97c1b735caa8e4

Comment: @KirillRakhman What about sorting multiple values with same comparator? For example CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)?

Comment: interesting, this is basically the same as [naturalOrdering](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/natural-order.html), although I like this solution better.

Answer (score 2):

If you need sort by multiple fields, and some field by descending and others by ascending you could use:

```
YOUR_MUTABLE_LIST.sortedWith(compareBy<YOUR_OBJECT> { it.PARAM_1}.thenByDescending { it.PARAM_2}.thenBy { it.PARAM_3})
```

Comment: This is covered in my answer.

Comment: E.g. return ```bookingRepository.findAll().sortedWith(compareBy(Booking::isDeleted).thenByDescending(Booking::createdAt))```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort in descending order, you can use the accepted answer:

```
list.sortedWith(compareByDescending<Foo> { it.a }.thenByDescending { it.b }.thenByDescending { it.c })
```

Or create an extension function like `compareBy`:

```
/**
 * Similar to
 * public fun <T> compareBy(vararg selectors: (T) -> Comparable<*>?): Comparator<T>
 *
 * but in descending order.
 */
public fun <T> compareByDescending(vararg selectors: (T) -> Comparable<*>?): Comparator<T> {
    require(selectors.size > 0)
    return Comparator { b, a -> compareValuesByImpl(a, b, selectors) }
}

private fun <T> compareValuesByImpl(a: T, b: T, selectors: Array<out (T) -> Comparable<*>?>): Int {
    for (fn in selectors) {
        val v1 = fn(a)
        val v2 = fn(b)
        val diff = compareValues(v1, v2)
        if (diff != 0) return diff
    }
    return 0
}
```

and use: `list.sortedWith(compareByDescending ({ it.a }, { it.b }, { it.c }))`.