# How to change the order of compareBy in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, comparable

I need a comparator, in Kotlin, to order every object that enter in my recycler view (using Fast Adapter).

I need to order the objects by an Integer, where the biggest ones come first.

The code above order the object that enters in my list, but the biggest ones is in the end of the list. Is there a way to reverse the order?

```
playersFastAdapter.itemAdapter.withComparator(compareBy({ it.player.goals }, {it.player.assists}), true)
```

Comment: Useful question about sorting in Kotlin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640864/how-to-sort-based-on-compare-multiple-values-in-kotlin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
mylist.sortWith(compareBy<Player> { it.name }.thenBy { it.age }.thenBy { it.gender })
```

or

```
mylist.sortWith(compareByDescending<Player> { it.name }
    .thenByDescending { it.age }.thenBy { it.gender })
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. And put some explanation on the code, instead of dumping the code alone

Comment: I formatted the code, but not sure it works right. At least, it returns `Unit` instead of list. Better see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37259482/2914140.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by [Mitja Slenc](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/u/mslenc) on [Kotlin forum](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-to-change-the-order-of-compareby-in-kotlin/4696):

Changed to `compareBy({ -it.player.goals}, {-it.player.assists})`

And now it's working the way I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

you can always use `compareByDescending`

Comment: Thanks for the help, but looks like compareByDescending do not support more than one field on the comparison.