# How to sort based on multiple types and values in Kotlin?

Tags: sorting, kotlin, comparator, comparable

Given following classes:

```
interface Item {
    val name: String
}

data class Server(override val name: String, val id: String) : Item
data class Local(override val name: String, val date: Int) : Item
data class Footer(override val name: String) : Item
```

If we create a list:

```
val items = arrayListOf<Item>()
items.add(Server("server", "b"))
items.add(Local("local", 2))
items.add(Footer("footer"))
items.add(Server("server", "a"))
items.add(Local("local", 1))
items.add(Footer("footer"))
items.add(Server("server", "c"))
items.add(Local("local", 0))
```

And sort it:

```
val groupBy = items.groupBy { it.name }

val partialSort = arrayListOf<Item>()

//individually sort each type
partialSort.addAll(groupBy["local"]!!.map { it as Local }.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.date })))
partialSort.addAll(groupBy["server"]!!.map { it as Server }.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.id })))
partialSort.addAll(groupBy["footer"]!!.map { it as Footer })

//this can be avoided if above three lines are rearranged
val fullSort = partialSort.sortedWith(compareBy({ it is Footer }, { it is Local }, { it is Server }))
```

Then I get a list which looks like if it was created by following commented code:

```
//        items.add(Server("server", "a"))
//        items.add(Server("server", "b"))
//        items.add(Server("server", "c"))
//        items.add(Local("local", 0))
//        items.add(Local("local", 1))
//        items.add(Local("local", 2))
//        items.add(Footer("footer"))
//        items.add(Footer("footer"))
```

Is there a better way to sort it this way?
I read [How to sort based on/compare multiple values in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640864/how-to-sort-based-on-compare-multiple-values-in-kotlin)
and [Sort collection by multiple fields in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37259159/sort-collection-by-multiple-fields-in-kotlin) already but couldn't apply that to my code.

Comment: Is there an assumption that the subclass type and the name property is always the same (case-insensitive)?

Comment: I would love an answer that doesn't assume that. But sure lets say subclass type and the name property is always same.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it can be achieved in single operation (but pretty complex one) and you're thinking in right way, `compareBy` can do the trick for you

```
items.sortWith(compareBy({
    when (it) {
        is Server -> -1
        is Local -> 0
        is Footer -> 1
        else -> Integer.MAX_VALUE
    }
}, {
    when (it) {
        is Server -> it.id
        is Local -> it.date
        else -> 0
    }
}))
```

What we do here:

1. We're creating syntetic comparator for implementations of Item. Of course this number may be just another field in interface if that's common usecase.
2. We're defining fields to compare on `Server` and `Local` because they have additional criterion of sorting.
3. And we're passing comparators created on steps 1 and 2 to `compareBy` function.

After this operation `items` collections is sorted:

```
[Server(name=server, id=a), Server(name=server, id=b), Server(name=server, id=c), Local(name=local, date=0), Local(name=local, date=1), Local(name=local, date=2), Footer(name=footer), Footer(name=footer)]
```

**UPD**: If name of `Item` shoud be subject of sorting too — you can easily add one more comparator like `Item::name` in appropriate place.