# Change the positions of list elements with some conditions

Tags: arraylist, kotlin, hashmap

I have a list of strings like this :-

```
listOf("abc", "a", "bb", "aa", "aaa", "bb", "a")
```

I want an output like this :-

```
listOf("a", "a", "aa", "bb", "bb", "aaa", "abc")
```

First I want to sort list by length and then again sort that length group by letters.

I tried below code so far

```
fun main() {
    val result = listOf("abc", "a", "bb", "aa", "aaa", "bb", "a").groupBy { it.length }
    val valueList = ArrayList(result.values).flatMap { it.toList() }
    println(valueList)
}
```

But the result I got is like below

```
[abc, aaa, a, a, bb, aa, bb]
```

After @Sergey Lagutin's duplication comment 
I also tried

```
val sortedList = a.sortedWith(compareBy { it.length })
```

Which is not returning the desired result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort based on/compare multiple values in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640864/how-to-sort-based-on-compare-multiple-values-in-kotlin)

Comment: The example from [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/natural-order.html) should work.

Comment: The original problem in the code was that `groupBy` function returns an unsorted Map, so `result.values` has to be sorted by key values first. There is no need to wrap `result.values` with ArrayList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val a = listOf("abc", "a", "bb", "aa", "aaa", "bb", "a")
a.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.length }, { it })) // [a, a, aa, bb, bb, aaa, abc]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way

```
val yourList = listOf("abc", "a", "bb", "aa", "aaa", "bb", "a")
val yourSortedList = yourList.sorted().sortedBy { it.length }
```

- **sorted** will sort you list according to their natural sort order. In this case it will be alphabetic order.
- With **sortyBy** you precise that the sort order is the length of your string.

Result `[a, a, aa, bb, bb, aaa, abc]`

Answer (score 0):

Use `sortedWith` function on the collection

```
val a = listOf("abc", "a", "bb", "aa", "aaa", "bb", "a")
val b = a.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.length }, { it }))
println(b)
```

Comment: `thenComparing` requires minimum api level 24

Comment: You may pass several lambdas to the `compareBy` function. I'll update the example.