# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract giving Error in java7

Tags: java

In this code  `result = myDef.getRank() - inDef.getRank();`
I am getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:` Comparison method violates its general contract!

Below is the code snippet . Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
public int compareTo(Object inObj) {
    int result = 0;
    if (inObj instanceof OmsFeatureFacade) {
        OmsFeatureFacade inFeature = (OmsFeatureFacade) inObj;

        FeatureDefinition inDef = inFeature.getFeatureDefinition();
        FeatureDefinition myDef = getFeatureDefinition();

        if ((inDef == null) || (myDef == null) ) {
            return result;
        }

        // Handling of primary feature.
        if (myDef.isPrimary() != inDef.isPrimary()) {
            if (myDef.isPrimary()) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (inDef.isPrimary()) {
                return 1;
            }
        }

        // Place all bolt on features under primary
        if (myDef.isPrimaryPricePlan() != inDef.isPrimaryPricePlan()) {
            if (myDef.isPrimaryPricePlan()) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (inDef.isPrimaryPricePlan()) {
                return 1;
            }
        }

        // Handling of SC feature.
        if (this.isSysGeneratedFeature() != inFeature.isSysGeneratedFeature()) {
            if (this.isSysGeneratedFeature()) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (inFeature.isSysGeneratedFeature()) {
                return 1;
            }
        }

        // First Sort by rank asc, if no rank, then getRank() returns very large number.
        result = myDef.getRank() - inDef.getRank();
        if (result != 0) {
            return result;
        }



        // Group by price plan, and sort alpha asc.
        result = myDef.getPricePlanCode().compareTo(inDef.getPricePlanCode());
        if (result != 0) {
            return result;
        }

        // Handling of main feature for price plan.
        if (this.isMainFeature() != inFeature.isMainFeature()) {
            if (this.isMainFeature()) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (inFeature.isMainFeature()) {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        // Sort alpha asc.
        result = myDef.getDescription().compareTo(inDef.getDescription());
        if (result != 0) {
            return result;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I guess your function never returns zero which is the case for equality.

Comment: Please send the full `compareTo` method. Things are mostly okay so far.

Comment: either `myDef.getRank()` or `inDef.getRank()` is returning a value that cannot be used with `minus` operator

Comment: Most likely comparison is inconsistent: `a.compareTo(b)` returns value of **the same sign** as `b.compareTo(a)` for some `a` and `b`.

Comment: tamas rev, Please find the full code of this method.

Comment: if i write like this if(myDef.getRank() > inDef.getRank()) { return -1}; if(myDef.getRank() < inDef.getRank()) { return 1}; then it is working fine only . cam we code like this please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Using substraction `myDef.getRank() - inDef.getRank()`in `compareTo` methods is generally a bad practice because it can result in integer overflow problems. See more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728793/java-integer-compareto-why-use-comparison-vs-subtraction).

There are two problematic parts with this:

1. `result = myDef.getRank() - inDef.getRank();` - it has integer overflow problems. You can fix it like this: `result = new Integer(myDef.getRank()).compareTo(inDef.getRank());`
2. `if (inObj instanceof OmsFeatureFacade) {` - if you implement `Comparable<OmsFeatureFacade>` (watch out for generics) then you can skip this part.
  3.

Comment: //this is the implementation of  public int getRank() {
        if (rank == null) {
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        return rank.intValue();
    }

Comment: @ShubhamAgrawal an Integer.MAX_VALUE combined with the substraction is a typical int overflow situation. Apply the fix I suggested and this part will be fine.

Comment: @tamasrev or just use [`Integer.compare()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-) which handles possible overflows as well.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou that's fine too. Added it to the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to say what's wrong with your code. The reason can be in the rest of compareTo method or in the getRank() implementation.

I can only recommend you to check this rules of compareTo implementation:

> The implementor must ensure sgn(x.compareTo(y)) ==
>   -sgn(y.compareTo(x)) for all x and y. (This implies that x.compareTo(y) must throw an exception iff y.compareTo(x) throws an
>   exception.)
>
> The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive:
>   (x.compareTo(y)>0 && y.compareTo(z)>0) implies x.compareTo(z)>0.
>
> Finally, the implementor must ensure that x.compareTo(y)==0 implies
>   that sgn(x.compareTo(z)) == sgn(y.compareTo(z)), for all z.
>
> In the foregoing description, the notation sgn(expression) designates
>   the mathematical signum function, which is defined to return one of
>   -1, 0, or 1 according to whether the value of expression is negative, zero or positive.