# Java Collections.sort() not working even though comparable is declared

Tags: java, sorting, comparable

Here is my interface class

```
public interface Thing {
    int getVolume();
}
```

And here is the class which implements Thing

Item.java

```
public class Item implements Thing, Comparable<Thing> {
    private String name;
    private int volume;

    public Item(String name,int volume){
        this.name = name;
        this.volume = volume;
    }

    @Override
    public int getVolume() {
        return this.volume;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return name+" ("+volume+" dm^3)";
    }

 //   @Override
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Thing another) {
        if(this.getVolume()  < another.getVolume()){
            return -1;
        }

        if(this.getVolume() == another.getVolume()){
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            return 1;
        }
    }

}
```

When I try to run the main program with the following commands it runs fine 
// main program.java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // test your program here
     List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    items.add(new Item("passport", 2));
    items.add(new Item("toothbrash", 1));
    items.add(new Item("circular saw", 100));

    Collections.sort(items);
    System.out.println(items);



    }
}
```

But when I try to run Collections.sort() on another class which implements the Thing interface, I get an error

here is the box class which implements the Thing interface and when I try to run the Collections.sort(store) in the void sort() function it gives an error even the store is a List and the Box class implements Thing interface and I have defined comparable for Thing in the Item.java class

Box.java

```
public class Box implements Thing {

    private int maximumCapacity;
    private List<Thing> store;

    public Box(int maximumCapacity) {
        this.maximumCapacity = maximumCapacity;
        this.store = new ArrayList<Thing>();
    }

    public boolean addThing(Thing thing) {
        // I.E. if the item added does not make the total volume go to max capacity only
        // then add
        if (this.getVolume() + thing.getVolume() < this.maximumCapacity) {
            store.add(thing);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getVolume() {
        // we calculate things of all items in the boxes (current value)
        int currentWeight = 0;
        for (Thing t : store) {
            currentWeight += t.getVolume();
        }
        return currentWeight;
    }

    public List<Thing> getStore() {
        return store;
    }

    public int numOfItems(){
        return this.store.size();
    }


     public void sort(){ 

        Collections.sort(store); // *****does not work ****//

     }

}
```

> It gives an error above for sort as "No suitable method found for
>   sort(List <Thing>)."

My question is if it can work in the main.java program where the items are given as List then why can it not work here ?
How to fix it?

Comment: your `Box` class does not implement `Comparable`. How do you expect `sort` to know how to sort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It the main class you sort a `List<Item>` where `Item implements Thing, Comparable<Thing>`.

In the `Box` class you try to sort `List<Thing>`, but `Thing` itself does not implement `Comparable<Thing>`. Therefore Java doesn't know how to sort `Thing`s.

To fix it you either have to provide a comparator for two `Thing`s (as proposed by Александр Нестеров) or you declare `Thing implements Comparable<Thing>`:

```
public interface Thing extends Comparable<Thing>{

    int getVolume();

    //provide default method to sort any class which implements Thing
    @Override
    public default int compareTo(Thing another) {
        return Integer.compare(this.getVolume(), another.getVolume());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much I did it by making a separate Comparator  public class Sort implements Comparator<Thing> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Thing o1, Thing o2) {
        if(o1.getVolume() < o2.getVolume()){
            return -1;
        }
        
        if(o1.getVolume() == o2.getVolume()){
            return 0;
        }
        
        else{
            return 1;
        }
    }
    
     
}  and using Collections.sort(store, new Sort()).               
 but I didnt understood how to do this line of yours: "or you declare Thing implements Comparable<Thing>"

Answer (score 3):

It's because in first you sort "item", in second you sort "list thing" 
So, you can fix it by using lambda:

```
Collections.sort(store, (o1, o2) -> {
your implementation of comparator
});
```

Comment: If you are using jdk 8 or above and want all classes implementing "Thing" should be sorted on the bases of same parameter you should change your interface to this:

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you define Thing to extend Comparable, given your application doesn't work when you add classes not being Comparable.

By the way, your compareTo looks rather complicated. Do this instead:

```
int compareTo(Thing another) {
    return this.getVolume()  - another.getVolume();
    }
```

Comment: The `compareTo` method is implemented correctly. For a reason why your implementation is wrong look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/2728793/5646962

Answer (score 0):

In the first program, you have

```
public class Item implements Thing, Comparable<Thing>
```

But in the second, you just have

```
public class Box implements Thing
```

If you want sort to work, you need to either implement Comparable or Comparator (separate class implementing just Comparator).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jdk 8 or above and want all classes implementing "Thing" should be sorted on the bases of same parameter you should change your interface to this to provide default sorting capability:

```
//extend your interface with comparable

public interface Thing extends Comparable<Thing>{

int getVolume();

//provide default method to sort any class which implements Thing
@Override
public default int compareTo(Thing another) {
    if(this.getVolume()  < another.getVolume()){
        return -1;
    }

    if(this.getVolume() == another.getVolume()){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return 1;
    }
}

}
```

Now Item and Box only needs to implement Thing interface.

Please try to optimize compareTo() method also as suggested by 
@Jo Witters

Answer (score -1):

Make Thing an abstract class implementing Comparable , so that Thing is always ready for sorting . Item can be extended from Thing