# Add additional rules to the compare method of a Comparator

Tags: java, android, comparator

I currently have a code snippet which returns strings of a list in ascending order:

```
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<MyClass>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyClass o1, MyClass o2) {
        return o1.aString.compareTo(o2.aString);
    }
});
```

While it works, I would like to add some custom "rules" to the order to put certain strings to the front. For instance:

```
if(aString.equals("Hi")){
// put string first in the order
}

if(aString begins with a null character, e.g. " ") {
// put string after Hi, but before the other strings
}

// So the order could be: Hi, _string, a_string, b_string, c_string
```

Is it possible to customize the sorting of a list with a `Comparator` like this?

Comment: Note that you are comparing strings with `==`. Never do that. Second, you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: class names should start with uppercase. Third, you could replace your `Comparator` with a lambda expression: `(t, u) -> { /* your rules */ return ...; }`.

Comment: @MCEmperor Thank you for the advice. I will try to edit the question according to your suggestions. I'm still new to java, so I appreciate feedback on best practices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's possible.

#### Using Java 8 features

You could pass a function to the `Comparator.comparing` method to define your rules. Note that we simply return integers, the lowest integer for the elements which should come first.

```java
Comparator<MyClass> myRules = Comparator.comparing(t -> {
    if (t.aString.equals("Hi")) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (t.aString.startsWith(" ")) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 2;
    }
});
```

If you want the remaining elements to be sorted alphabetically, you could use `thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder())`, if your class implements `Comparable`. Otherwise, you should extract the sort key first:

```java
Collections.sort(myList, myRules.thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(t -> t.aString)));
```

Note that the actual specific numbers returned don't matter, what matters is that lower numbers come before higher numbers when sorting, so if one would always put the string "Hi" first, then the corresponding number should be the lowest returned (in my case 0).

#### Using Java <= 7 features (Android API level 21 compatible)

If Java 8 features are not available to you, then you could implement it like this:

```java
Comparator<MyClass> myRules = new Comparator<MyClass>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(MyClass o1, MyClass o2) {
        int order = Integer.compare(getOrder(o1), getOrder(o2));
        return (order != 0 ? order : o1.aString.compareTo(o2.aString));
    }

    private int getOrder(MyClass m) {
        if (m.aString.equals("Hi")) {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (m.aString.startsWith(" ")) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return 2;
        }
    }
};
```

And call it like this:

```java
Collections.sort(list, myRules);
```

This works as follows: first, both received strings are mapped to your custom ruleset and subtracted from eachother. If the two differ, then the operation `Integer.compare(getOrder(o1), getOrder(o2))`<sup>1</sup> determines the comparison. Otherwise, if both are the same, then the lexiographic order is used for comparison.

[Here is some code in action](https://ideone.com/BbEOHb).

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Always use `Integer::compare` rather than subtracting one from the other, because of the risk of erroneous results due to integer overflow. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728793/java-integer-compareto-why-use-comparison-vs-subtraction).</sup>

Comment: Hello MC Emperor, I guess I forgot to mention it, but I'm currently facilitating a minimum API of 21, so I got an error here: `Comparator<String> myRules = Comparator.comparing(t -> {}`. It said that `Comparator.comparing` requires API level 24.

Comment: This is preferable to the [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54224703/1441122), which has several errors. +1. Also, were you going to rewrite this to avoid use of Java 8 APIs?

Comment: @StuartMarks I think I might do that indeed.

Comment: I think you could just add an equivalent for lower APIs. If it works for my needs and fixes the errors, I'll consider changing the answer.

Comment: @ErlendKH I've updated the answer an added equivalent code without Java 8 features.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I tested it, and it gave the order I was looking for. May I suggest swapping the return values for `aString.equals("Hi")` and `aString.startsWith(" ")`, as I originally asked to put the string equation first in the order. Also, another small thing, perhaps add `Collections.sort(list, myRules);` under the Comparator, so new users can see how to call it. `private int getOrder(MyClass m) {}` is brilliant. Does it work to put return values above 2 (to add even more conditions)?

Comment: @ErlendKH I will swap the values, so the code matches the requirements. It works too if more conditions are added, one must simply make sure that all returned values are different for each case.

Comment: Good update! The only thing I'll add is that I prefer to avoid subtraction to compute values returned from a comparison method, because of potential integer overflow. This can't happen in this case, of course, but it could be a trap for an unwary programmer who repurposes the code. I use `Integer.compare` instead of subtraction.

Comment: @StuartMarks Good catch, I've added it. Those are details, but yet very important details. A detail like this is easily missed, so I'm glad you brought it up.

Answer (score 6):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54226222/1441122) from MC Emperor is quite nice (+1) in that it fulfills the OP's requirement of not using Java 8 APIs. It also uses a neat internal function technique (the `getOrder` method) of mapping conditions to small integer values in order to effect a first-level comparison.

Here's an alternative that uses Java 8 constructs. It assumes that `MyClass` has a `getString` method that does the obvious thing.

```
    Collections.sort(myList,
        Comparator.comparing((MyClass mc) -> ! mc.getString().equals("Hi"))
                  .thenComparing(mc -> ! mc.getString().startsWith(" "))
                  .thenComparing(MyClass::getString));
```

This is pretty opaque until you get used to this style. The key insight is that the "extractor" function that's supplied to `Comparator.comparing` and `Comparator.thenComparing` often simply extracts a field, but it can be a general mapping to any other value. If that value is Comparable then an additional Comparator for it needn't be provided. In this case the extractor function is a boolean expression. This gets boxed to a Boolean which as it turns out is Comparable. Since `false` orders before `true` we need to negate the boolean expression.

Also note that I had to provide an explicit type declaration for the lambda parameter, as type inference often doesn't work for chained comparator cases such as this one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible, you have complete control over the compareTo() method. Two things:

1. Use String#equals instead of == to compare strings
2. Make sure you check both arguments to compareTo for your exceptional cases.

A concrete way of implementing something where some words are always first and some words are always last, with ordering defined among the exceptions:

```
Map<String, Integer> exceptionMap = new HashMap<>();
exceptionMap.put("lowest", -2);
exceptionMap.put("second_lowest", -1);
exceptionMap.put("second_highest", 1);
exceptionMap.put("highest", 2);

public int compareToWithExceptionMap(String s1, String s2) {
  int firstExceptional = exceptionMap.getOrDefault(s1, 0);
  int secondExceptional = exceptionMap.getOrDefault(s2, 0);

  if (firstExceptional == 0 && secondExceptional == 0) {
    return s1.compareTo(s2);
  }
  return firstExceptional - secondExceptional;
}
```