# Getting java.util.NoSuchElementException in the code. Why?

Tags: java, collections

I have the following code given below :

```
final LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> linkedHashMapCounterMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(); 
linkedHashMapCounterMap.put("abc", 2); 
linkedHashMapCounterMap.put("xyz", 5); 
final String maxColln = Collections.max(
            linkedHashMapCounterMap.entrySet(),
            (entry1, entry2) -> entry1.getValue().intValue() - 
                                entry2.getValue().intValue())
     .getKey();
```

After running the code, I'm getting this exception :

> java.util.NoSuchElementException: null at
>   java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_202] at
>   java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:752)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_202] at
>   java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:750)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_202] at java.util.Collections.max(Collections.java:708)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_202]

Comment: It works with me in Java-8 and Java-13, can you please show us what are your imports? also which version of Java you are using?

Answer (score 1):

There is an edge-case bug in the comparator lambda, but that shouldn't cause an NPE.  (Use `Integer.compareTo(Integer)`:  see [Java Integer compareTo() - why use comparison vs. subtraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728793/java-integer-compareto-why-use-comparison-vs-subtraction))

I think that the NPE must be due to a threading bug; e.g. there is another thread modifying the map while this code is running.  I cannot see how this code could NPE in `next()`, in any other way.

Either way, we need a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to take this any further.