# Unexpected behaviour java priority queue. Object added once but polled out twice. How could it be possible?

Tags: java, debugging, data-structures, priority-queue

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Solution solution = new Solution();
        int[] res = solution.assignTasks(new int[]{3,3,2}, new int[]{1,2,3,2,1,2});
    }
}
class Solution {
    public int[] assignTasks(int[] servers, int[] tasks) {
        PriorityQueue<Pair> free = new PriorityQueue(); // (wt, id, time)
        PriorityQueue<Pair> busy = new PriorityQueue(); // (time, wt, id)
        
        for (int i = 0; i < servers.length; i++) {
            free.add(new Pair(servers[i], i, 0));
            System.out.println("Free Added " + i + " " + servers[i] + " " + i + " " + 0 + " " + free.size());
        }
        
        int[] ans = new int[tasks.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
            Pair b = busy.peek();
            while (b != null && b.a <= i) {
                busy.poll();
                System.out.println("Busy Polled " + i + " " + b.a + " " + b.b + " " + b.c + " " + busy.size());
                free.add(new Pair(b.b, b.c, b.a));
                System.out.println("Free Added " + i + " " + b.b + " " + b.c + " " + b.a + " " + free.size());
                b = busy.peek();
            }
            Pair p = free.poll();
            
            int wt = p.a;
            int id = p.b;
            
            // int time = p.c;
            System.out.println("Free Polled " + i + " " + p.a + " " + p.b + " " + p.c + " " + free.size());
            
            ans[i] = id;
            busy.add(new Pair(i + tasks[i], wt, id));
            System.out.println("Added to Busy " + i + " " + (i + tasks[i]) + " " + p.a + " " + p.b + " " + busy.size());
        }
        
        return ans;
    }
}
class Pair implements Comparable<Pair> {
    int a, b, c;
    Pair(int x, int y, int z) {
        a = x;
        b = y;
        c = z;
    }
    public int compareTo(Pair p) {
         if (this.a == p.a) {
             if (this.b == p.b) return this.c - p.c;
             return this.b = p.b;
         }
         return this.a - p.a;
     }
    
}
```

I have inserted triplets using Pair class in the priority queue and **one pair is polled from the queue two times and was inserted only once. How it could be possible?**
I am also attaching the console output for print statements I added to debug. Highlighted the unusual behavior.

The output of Code: (Note the behavior in output. Highlighting it (3,0,0) polled twice?)

```
Free Added 0 3 0 0 1       (Added to the queue)
Free Added 1 3 1 0 2
Free Added 2 2 2 0 3
Free Polled 0 2 2 0 2
Added to Busy 0 1 2 2 1
Busy Polled 1 1 2 2 0
Free Added 1 2 2 1 3
Free Polled 1 2 2 1 2
Added to Busy 1 3 2 2 1
Free Polled 2 3 0 0 1     (Polled 1st time)
Added to Busy 2 5 3 0 2
Busy Polled 3 3 2 2 1
Free Added 3 2 2 3 2
Free Polled 3 2 2 3 1
Added to Busy 3 5 2 2 2
Free Polled 4 3 0 0 0     (Polled 2nd time)
Added to Busy 4 5 3 0 3
Busy Polled 5 5 3 0 2
Free Added 5 3 0 5 1
Busy Polled 5 5 3 0 1
Free Added 5 3 0 5 2
Busy Polled 5 5 3 2 0
Free Added 5 3 2 5 3
Free Polled 5 3 0 5 2
Added to Busy 5 7 3 0 1
```

The question was from a recent Leetcode Contest that was over now. Link to the [discussion](https://leetcode.com/problems/process-tasks-using-servers/discuss/1239992/Java-Unexpected-Behaviour-Priority-Queue-or-Help-or-Socked-or-Unable-to-Spot-bug-or-Wasted-greater-1-hour) section of the question. Link to [question](https://leetcode.com/problems/process-tasks-using-servers/)
Link to IDE [run](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/C9DhVf2vyu)

Comment: `return this.b = p.b`. You should not be assigning to one of the objects in a `compareTo()` method. You should probably be returning `this.b - p.b` at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not entirely clear, but I think your problem is caused by an incorrect implementation of `compareTo`.

```
public int compareTo(Pair p) {
     if (this.a == p.a) {
         if (this.b == p.b) return this.c - p.c;
         return this.b = p.b;
     }
     return this.a - p.a;
 }
```

### Problem #1

```
return this.b = p.b;
```

This returns `p.b` and as a side-effect it assigns `p.b` to `this.b`.  This is completely wrong.

It is possible that you mean `return this.b - p.b;`

Note that since your `compareTo` method is *changing* one of the `Pair` objects, the results are going to be messed up.  That's probably why some of the `Pair` objects *appear* to be returned more than once.  (In fact, they are different `Pair` objects ... but you have mutated them so that they have the same values in the `c` field.)

### Problem #2

The expression `this.c - p.c` gives an incorrect answer in edge cases.  For example, `this.c` is very large and `p.c` is negative, then the subtraction may overflow to a negative number which says that `this.c` is "less" than `p.c` ... which it isn't.

See [Java Integer compareTo() - why use comparison vs. subtraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728793) for a more on this.

Here are a couple of correct ways to compare two `int` values to give a result that is compatible with the `compareTo` contract:

1. Longhand:

   ```
   if (this.c == p.c) {
       return 0;
   } else if (this.c < p.c) {
       return -1;
   } else {
       return +1;
   }
   ```
2. Using conditional expressions:

   ```
   return (this.c == p.c) ? 0 : ((this.c < p.c) ? -1 : +1);
   ```
3. Using `Integer.compare`

   ```
   return Integer.compare(this.c, p.c);
   ```

### Correct implementation

If we assume that the `Pair` objects are supposed to be immutable, then this is a correct<sup>1</sup> implementation:

```
class Pair implements Comparable<Pair> {
    final int a, b, c;

    Pair(int x, int y, int z) {
        a = x;
        b = y;
        c = z;
    }

    public int compareTo(Pair p) {
        if (this.a == p.a) {
            if (this.b == p.b) {
                return Integer.compare(this.c, p.c);
            } else {
                return Integer.compare(this.b, p.b);
            }
        } else {
            return Integer.compare(this.a, p.a);
        }
    }
}
```

Q: Why declare the fields as `final` ?
A: To prevent *accidental* changes to the fields, within the `Pair` class itself and also by other classes to which the class and its fields are accessible.

Q: Why use `if ... else`?
A: Because it is clearer.  And because the JIT compiler should generate equivalent  (optimal) code in either case.

Q: What about `compare`?  Won't the method call be inefficient?
A: Probably not.  The method call will probably be inlined by the JIT compiler.

Q: Does efficiency matter at all?
A: In your example it is irrelevant.  In the general case, it is **probably** irrelevant<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - The class name `Pair` is also incorrect.  It should be `Triple`. 

2 - You should only try to hand optimize this after you have 1) benchmarked your code, 2) profiled it, and 3) determined that the `compareTo` method is *really* a performance hotspot.</sup>