# Java Comporator Of Integer Array

Tags: java, lambda, syntax, type-erasure

I'm trying to make a priority queue that orders integer arrays by the value of the first element, but I am running into an issue that the complier is complaining that an array is requred in my Comporator lambda expression. Any idea on what I'm screwing up?

`PriorityQueue<int[]> kNearest = new PriorityQueue((a, b) -> b[0] > a[0]);`

```
Line 22: error: array required, but Object found
        PriorityQueue<int[]> kNearest = new PriorityQueue((a, b) -> b[0] > a[0]);
                                                                     ^
Line 22: error: array required, but Object found
        PriorityQueue<int[]> kNearest = new PriorityQueue((a, b) -> b[0] > a[0]);
```

Comment: new PriorityQueue((a, b) -> b[0] > a[0]) does not return an array

Comment: Thank you! I forgot the diamond operator. I also messed up my comporator by returning a boolean rather than an int. 


Fixed version: 
``` PriorityQueue<int[]> kNearest = new PriorityQueue<int[]>((a, b) -> b[0] - a[0]);```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Kiran and zatef! I forgot the diamond operator. I also messed up my comporator by returning a boolean rather than an int.

Fixed version:
 `PriorityQueue<int[]> kNearest = new PriorityQueue<int[]>((a, b) -> b[0] - a[0]);`

Comment: See my comment above.  Subtraction is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

To simply answer your question, you are returning a boolean instead of an integer as required by the comparator.

Try simply the following:

```
PriorityQueue<int[]> kNearest = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> Integer.compare(b[0],a[0]));
```

This will order the items based on smaller values of b[0] in comparison to a[0].

The comparator here checks for equality and returns the following:

'< 0' (e.g. -1) when the first parameter is smaller

'0' when both the params are equal.

'> 0' (e.g. 1) when the 2nd parameter is smaller

**Update:** As pointed out by @Stephen C in comments, a subtraction is not full proof. For details, please view [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728793). The answer is updated to make use of the Integer.compare(int, int) method.

Comment: This is half right.  The problem is that `i - j` doesn't return the required values for ALL values of `i` and `j`.  Use Integer.compare(int, int)`.   See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728793

Comment: You are correct, this is something many often miss and should in fact be the better practice. Thanks I updated the answer.