# How to initialize a HashMap with max Heap using Lambda in Java

Tags: java, lambda, hashmap, priority-queue

In Java, initialization of a hash map with a min heap as the value:

```
Map<Integer, PriorityQueue<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Initialization of a max heap using lambda can be like:

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> b - a);
```

However, how to initialize a hash map with a max heap using lambda?

This definitly doesn't work.

```
Map<Integer, PriorityQueue<Integer>((a, b) -> b - a)> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You can't add values to a map without keys.

Comment: @shmosel but in the background Java has allocated a default capacity of 16 HashMap entries. @mmast can do `Map<Integer, PriorityQueue<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();` which in the background would allocate space for 16 HashMap entries and 11 PriorityQueue entries for each of those HashMap entries but they are trying to override the default behaviour using lambda functions.

Comment: @Puddler since Java 8 constructing a new `HashMap` instance does **not** create the `table` - this is only done on first use (i.e. first `put()` operation). But even if it did allocate the `table` field it would only allocate an array full of `null` values. The `HashMap` only ever allocates its internal objects, it neither allocates the keys nor the values.

Comment: @ThomasKläger and that's why I only commented and didn't give an answer since my Java is clearly very rusty., thanks for the correction.

Comment: Your terminology is somewhat deviated here.  In your examples you are just instantiating objects which utilize a dynamic heap allocation, in terms of memory.  Are you referencing another coding language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not "initialise of a hash map with a min heap as the value".

```
Map<Integer, PriorityQueue<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

This creates a `HashMap`, whose keys are integers, and whose values are `PriorityQueue<Integer>`s.

A `PriorityQueue<Integer>` can act like a max heap *or* a min heap, depending on the `Comparator<Integer>` that you pass into its constructor. This means that `map` above can contain *both* max heaps and min heaps.

```
map.put(1, new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.naturalOrder())); // a min heap is associated with the key 1
map.put(2, new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.reverseOrder())); // a max heap is associated with the key 2
```

Note that you should not use subtraction (i.e. `(a, b) -> b - a`) to compare integers. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2728793/5133585) for more info.

With that cleared out of the way, we can make a `HashMap` that *only* contains min heaps, or *only* contains max heaps, by declaring our own `MinHeap` and `MaxHeap` types.

`MinHeap` and `MaxHeap` can inherit from `PriorityQueue`, and calling `PriorityQueue`'s constructor with an appropriate `Comparator` argument.

```
class MinHeap<T extends Comparable<T>> extends PriorityQueue<T> {
    public MinHeap() {
        super(Comparator.naturalOrder());
    }
}

class MaxHeap<T extends Comparable<T>> extends PriorityQueue<T> {
    public MaxHeap() {
        super(Comparator.reverseOrder());
    }
}
```

Now, a `HashMap<Integer, MinHeap<Integer>>` only contains min heaps as values, and a `HashMap<Integer, MaxHeap<Integer>>` only max heaps as values.

```
Map<Integer, MinHeap<Integer>> minHeapMap = new HashMap<>();
Map<Integer, MaxHeap<Integer>> maxHeapMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: Note that `super(Comparator.naturalOrder())` can be simplified to `super()`.